# View PDF on Nuxt page

Tags: vue.js, pdf, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app and I want to display on a certain page e.g. /gdpr a PDF file with the GDPR policy. I tried to put the PDF in the static folder, but having something like /gdpr.pdf simply won't do.

I couldn't find a proper way to do this without any PDF viewer plugin and the vue-pdf one has lots of problems with Nuxt.

Any ideas or some other way of implementing this?

Answer (score 7):

You can simply embed your `PDF` in your page:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <embed src="/pdf/your_pdf_file.pdf" width="1440px" height="900px" />
    </div>
</template>
```

I put my pdf file in the pdf folder in my `static` folder of the project.

Comment: haha very simply, thanks bro!

Comment: how to add tools, like download ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <embed src="/pdf/your_pdf_file.pdf" width="1440px" height="900px" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Should be noted that if your pdf is multiple pages, this method does not work correctly on touch-screen devices.  FYI.  In my experience, it will render the first page of the document, but scrolling to a second page is not possible.